# unclassifiable statement error in fortran

Tags: fortran

the next program has an error and I don't know which is the trouble with.

```
 IMPLICIT NONE
        DOUBLE PRECISION X(100),W(100),lambdainv,g,lambda,alfac
        INTEGER i, N

        N=100
        alfac=939.D0*2.D22

        CALL GAUSS_L(1.D0,100.D0,100,X,W)

        lambdainv=0.D0

        DO i=1,N
          lambdainv=lambdainv+((W(i)*(X(i))**2)/(alfac+ 
     >              (X(i))**2))*g(X(i)))**2

        END DO

          lambda=lambdainv**(-1)

        WRITE(*,*)'lambda=', lambda

        STOP
        END

c       Funcion g
        DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION g(X)

        IMPLICIT NONE  
        DOUBLE PRECISION X, mu, pi

c       Inicializamos las variables
        mu=138.d0
        pi=ATAN(1.D0)*4.D0


        g=(2.d0*sqrt(mu**3))/((sqrt(pi))*(mu**2+X**2))

        RETURN
        END
```

The error is:

```
lambdainv=lambdainv+((W(i)*(X(i))**2)/(alfac+                 
          1

Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

thanks!!

Comment: Instead of `lambda=lambdainv**(-1)` you should write `lambda=1.d0/lambdainv`. If your compiler is not very clever and does not see what you are trying to achieve, it would try to actually carry out the power operation (which is very costly). It shouldn't matter here, but inside a loop it would be noticeable. The same holds for the `X**2`, better write it as `X*X` - although most compilers will detect this if the exponent is an `integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets are unbalanced in the corresponding line, when you take into account the continuation of that line!

Do you mean:

```
          lambdainv=lambdainv+( W(i)*X(i)**2 / (alfac+ 
     >              X(i)**2)*g(X(i)))**2
```

(This is a wild guess, of course!)